# Como obter o SQL final do JPA usando NamedQueries

Tags: java, jpa

Como obter o SQL que está sendo executado pelo JPA quando usamos  um createNamedQuery. Gostaria de ter o SQL executado para entender onde está o problema da query abaixo:

Chamada do NameQuery

```
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("buscarTodosItensAnalisePorCpfCnpjEDataMinima");
    query.setParameter("cpfCnpj", cpf);
    System.out.println("SQL : "  + query.toString());
    query.setParameter("data", dataPeriodo);
```

NamedQuery usado

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="buscarTodosItensAnalisePorCpfCnpj",query="SELECT i FROM ItemAnalise i WHERE i.cpfCnpj = :cpfCnpj"),
@NamedQuery(name="buscarTodosItensAnalisePorCpfCnpjEDataMinima",query="SELECT i FROM ItemAnalise i WHERE i.cpfCnpj = :cpfCnpj AND i.dataRegistro >= :data")
```

})

Estou usando:

```
System.out.println("SQL : "  + query.toString());
```

O resultado no console é:

```
SQL : EJBQueryImpl(ReadAllQuery(name="buscarTodosItensAnalisePorCpfCnpjEDataMinima" referenceClass=ItemAnalise sql="SELECT id, atividade_id, cpfcnpj, data_atualizacao, data_registro, login, situacao FROM item_analise WHERE ((cpfcnpj = ?) AND (data_registro >= ?))"))
```

Preciso ver o SQL com os parâmetros "?" com os valores passados!

Comment: Qual JPA *provider* está usando? Se precisar para mais de um, liste-os.

Comment: Bruno, estou usando `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` JPA 1.0 puro

Answer (score 0):

No persistence.xml

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
</properties>
```

depois basta olhar os seus arquivos de log

Comment: Samuel já está assim no persistence.xml. Eu estou usando **JPA puro** e no log está sendo exibido o mesmo que o console.

Comment: Samuel eu alterei para `value="ALL"` e no log ele **_printou_** o `[bind]` e pude ver que a data que estava sendo passada realmente não resultaria em nenhum registro. Outro detalhe importante é que deve ser incluído `query.setParameter("data",data,TemporalType.DATE)` para que o formato seja o mesmo definido no atributo. Obrigado. Devido ao meu perfil ainda não consigo **votar** nesta resposta, mas obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas, ao dispor!